# Why did the writer use future continuous in this example?

Tags: future

> These **will be arriving** with us in the next week and will be our last releases this year.

Does "will be arriving" imply that he has "no power" on the sending of the releases, I mean the sending of the releases   does not depend on the writer (he is not sending the releases)

I saw this example:

> John won't be driving to work any more after his arrest for being drunk at the wheel.

I was told that future continuous can be used in this example  because it does not depend on John. It is not his own will like in  my example :it does not depend on the writer 's will .

Do you think this was the reason for choosing future continuous in my example?

If it was him that was going to send the releases could the writer use "are arriving" because he could predict with "more precisions" when the releases  should be arriving.

Comment: Is that a written sentence or something from a taping? Also, what do you mean by releases? Movies or permissions? Please always provide context.

Comment: written sentence  releases means in this textvinyl  records

Comment: textvinyl records??  Please explain that.

Comment: oh sorry I've a mistake  it is a written sentence . This text  is about vinyl records

Answer (score 1):

The writer does use future continuous.

Mostly this is a stylistic choice, "These will arrive next week..." and "These are arriving next week..." would mean basically the same.

The choice to use a future continuous may be because the speaker views the arrival as a process that will take some time.  They might expect the releases (books? records?) to arrive over several days.

In any case the speaker has no control over when the releases arrive.  The speaker says nothing about *sending* them, so you can't assume anything about what or when the speaker will *send* the releases. But you might suppose that they will start sending as soon as the releases start arriving, or they might wait until they have all arrived.  Sending is under their control.

Comment: but "are arriving" is also considered as a process that will take some time . So as the delivery will take some time it is better to use future continuous. If the delivery was the same day or a day after the sending would present continous be  more adapted to this new context

Comment: There is quite a bit of free choice for the speaker here.  Using "are arriving" would suggest this will happen tomorrow following a timetable or schedule. The speaker could correctly have chosen any of the many ways English has for talking about the future.

Comment: by the way in the sentence " In any case the speaker has no control over when the releases arrive" does when mean "considering that ". I was surprised that you don't use the future because it is not a time clause such as " as soon as l get your email, I will phone you" .